# Expose Haskell-functions through foreign export ccall fails for CStrings

Tags: haskell, cstring, ffi

I made a short Haskell-program that exposes functions for C or Python. Followed http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html#ffi-library to the letter and that worked okay for exporting Ints.

Want to export Strings and made the program:

```
module Adder where

import CString

adder :: Int -> Int -> IO CString 
adder x y =  newCString(show(x+y))

foreign export ccall adder :: Int -> Int -> IO CString
```

That compiles okay when I do : ghc adder.hs
but it fails when linking to create a dll in Windows.

> ghc -shared -o adder.dll adder.o adder_stub.o StartEnd.o

The error:
adder.o:fake:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `__stginit_haskell98zm1zi1zi0zi1_CString_'

The StartEnd.o is compiled from the C-file that I copied from the haskell.org-site :

```
#include <Rts.h>
extern void __stginit_Adder(void);
void HsStart()
{
  int argc = 1;
  char* argv[] = {"ghcDll", NULL}; // argv must end with NULL
  // Initialize Haskell runtime
  char** args = argv;
  hs_init(&argc, &args);
  // Tell Haskell about all root modules
  hs_add_root(__stginit_Adder);
}
void HsEnd()
{
  hs_exit();
}
```

What must I do to be able to export Strings ??

Comment: Just as a note, I would avoid the f(g(x)) style and use either `f (g x)` or `f $ g x` or `f . g $ x`

Answer (score 2):

Try to import `Foreign.C.String` instead of the module `CString`.  GHC should recognize the module and link in the correct library.  On a Linux system, compiling static, I had the same issue you did (undefined ref).  When I altered that import, leaving me with the below code, everything worked.

My Haskell module (exporting functions):

```
$ cat so.hs
module Adder where

import Foreign.C.String

adder :: Int -> Int -> IO CString 
adder x y =  newCString(show(x+y))

foreign export ccall adder :: Int -> Int -> IO CString
```

My main C file (Which includes all the init and take down work inline, not pretty but this is just educational):

```
$ cat soMain.c
#include <Rts.h>
#include "so_stub.h"

extern void __stginit_Adder(void);

void main()
{
  char *str = NULL;
  int argc = 1;
  char* argv[] = {"ghcDll", NULL}; // argv must end with NULL
  // Initialize Haskell runtime
  char** args = argv;
  hs_init(&argc, &args);
  // Tell Haskell about all root modules
  hs_add_root(__stginit_Adder);

  // END INIT


  str = adder(1,2);
  printf("%s\n",str);

  // END MAIN START THE FINALIZERS
  hs_exit();


}
```

My commands:

```
$ ghc -c so.hs
$ ghc soMain.c so_stub.o so.o -o so -fforce-recomp
$ ./so
3
```

EDIT: Just a guess, but perhaps the `CString` import would work if you specified `{-# LANGUAGE Haskell98, ForeignFunctionInterface #-}`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Also needed to #include the stub-object and then it worked great.

Comment: As an aside, I've recently added a package to automatically export haskell functions, it can be found at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Hs2lib , even if you don't want to use it, it can be useful to see what the FFI code looks like. (use -T to keep intermediate files)